# Kind of pointer in Java

Tags: java, pointers, reference, nullpointerexception

I am trying to do the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class One {

    private ArrayList<Integer> list;

    public One() {
        addString(list);
        sysoutList(list);
    }

    public void sysoutList(ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list2.get(i));
        }
    }

    private void addString(ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(1);
        list2.add(2);
        list2.add(3);
        list2.add(4);
    }

}
```

The problem is, that sysoutList() throws a NullPointerException because list2 is null. It seems, that the initialization of list in addString() has no effects, because the class variable can't be referenced. In C++ I would solve this problem with pointers, but how can I do that in Java?

Comment: Remove `list2 = new ArrayList<>();` from the `addString` method, insert it at the beginning of the `One` constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember that [Java is pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/3735079).

If you reinstantiate a variable inside a method, the passed variable is left untouched. Your example does exactly that.

```
String myValue = "All your variables belong to us";

setValue(myValue);

System.out.println(myValue); //All your variables belong to us

void setValue(String v){
    v = "Hello World!";
}
```

You should initialize first your variable:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class One {

    private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public One() {
        addString(list);
        sysoutList(list);
    }

    public void sysoutList(ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list2.get(i));
        }
    }

    private void addString(ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        list2.removeAll();
        list2.add(1);
        list2.add(2);
        list2.add(3);
        list2.add(4);
    }

}
```

A list is a special case tough. You could think *with the add() method I'm pratically modifying the variable, so the modification shouldn't occur*. That's not true, why?

That's because you are passing *the value of the reference* for the list. If you assign a new value to that reference using the `new` keyword, you "loose" the object attached to it (you don't have its reference anymore).

But if you modify a property of that object (such as with the *add()* method) the reference for the object is still valid and thus you modify the original object.

We can make a similitude.

Imagine you have a kite attached to a string. Now you attach a new string to it and pass the newly created string to a friend.

If he cuts the string (aka creates a `new` one), he loses the reference to your kite and he can't reach it. He can attach a new kite and do all the modifications (aka `add()` something to it) that he wants, but it will never be *your* kite.

If he instead uses the string you gave to him to reach the kite and modify it, you'll receive a modified kite.

To remain in the similitude in your case you are creating a string with no kite (`list`) with `private ArrayList<Integer> list;` and then passing it to your friend creating a new string (`list2`). Now both you and your friend have a string with nothing attached.

He creates a new kite and attaches it to his string (`list2 = new ArrayList<>()`) but your string is still attached to nothing. When you try to fly your kite you'll notice that the kite simply doesn't exists (`null` reference).

First you have to create your own kite and attach your string (`private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`). When you pass it to your friend another string is attached to it (`list2`). Now your friend can use `list2` to modify your kite.

### EDIT

Regarding your other question, if *is possible to istantiate a variable in a method which is called from the constructor* the answer is **yes**, but such variable MUST be declared as `static` if you want to use it outside your method.

In the kite similitude is like you attach a kite to a string and you and your friend use the same string to operate on it (yep, holding hands).

For you becomes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class One {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> list;

    public One() {
        addString();
        sysoutList();
    }

    public void sysoutList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }

    private void addString() {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
    }

}
```

You don't need to pass the `ArrayList` around since you are using the same "kite string" everywhere in your program.

**NB:** If you call `sysoutList()` *before* `addString()` you'll still get a `NullPointerException` because list isn't initialized yet.

This is a bad practice. I firmly suggest you to change your logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to instantiate the class variable in the method, called by the constructor you could do it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class One {

    private ArrayList<Integer> list;

    public One() {

        addString();
    }

    private void addString() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate your list :

```
private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();  //In 4th line
```

replace above in the place of :

```
private ArrayList<Integer> list;
```

Error is occuring because list was not initialized. You can also initialize it in the constructor.
Here is an example

```
public One() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    addString(list);
    sysoutList(list);
}
```

**Above diamond operator i.e. `<>` doesn't work in jdk prior to 7, you will need to use ` for that.**

Comment: OP also must remove the re-instantiation in the `addString` method